# C# 103 error. The name 'preview' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to C# programming. I was following some meme-maker C# code but when I type it in I get three 103 errors. ***"The name 'preview' does not exist in the current context   "***

here is the code.

```
namespace memeMaker
{
        public partial class Form1 : Form

    {
        OpenFileDialog openImage;
        string imageFile;
    

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void topText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            topLabel.Text = topText.Text;
            **topLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(preview.Width, 200);**
        }

        private void bottomText_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bottomLabel.Text = bottomText.Text;
            **bottomLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(preview.Width, 200);**
        }

        private void Open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

         

           openImage = new OpenFileDialog();
            openImage.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            openImage.Filter = "Image files (*.jpg, *.jpeg, *.jpe, *.jfif, *.png) |" +
                " *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jpe; *.jfif; *.png; *.gif; *.bmp;)";
openImage.FilterIndex = 2;
            openImage.RestoreDirectory = true;


            if (openImage.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               
                 try
                {
                  **preview.Image = Image.FromFile(openImage.FileName);**
                    imageFile = openImage.FileName;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'll be happy to resolve it

Comment: hi, what is `preview` supposed to be (I guess it is some Control)? and why do you expect it to be a part of `Form1`?

Comment: if your automatically generated click handler is called `topText_TextChanged` then your `TextBox` name is  highly probable not `topLabel` but `topText`, the same holds for `bottomText_TextChanged`